# deleting files only in sub folder using .batch

Tags: batch-file

i have a question. I need to delete all files in subfolders but not the sub folder or the main folder older than 1 day.

```
@echo off
    forfiles -p "C:\Users\remote\Downloads" -s -m *.* /D -1 -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

i have this code which delete all files older than 1 day in downloads but what i need /seek is:

```
C:\users\remote\downloads\%variable%
```

and that only the files whitin variable will be deleted. i have many "variables".

it is for my work and as a test i do it local.

Comment: Windows batch-files are not very handy for these kind of things. If you have the possibility, I would advise you to use a UNIX emulator, like Cygwin, for such purposes. The `find` command in there can easily do the things you ask for.

Comment: Are you saying the variable name will change or you are changing the assignment of the variable?

Comment: @Dominique its not possible.

Comment: @Squashman i am saying that %variable% coud be anything like: test or test1 or stuff or anything random

Answer (score 0):

`FOR /D` will allow you to iterate over subdirectories. How about

```
FOR /D %d IN (C:\Users\remote\Downloads\*) DO ( forfiles /P "%~d" /D -1 /C "cmd /c del @path" )
```

You'll need to "escape" the percent sign in the iteration variable if you put this command in a script:

```
FOR /D %%d IN (C:\Users\remote\Downloads\*) DO (
    FORFILES /P "%%~d" /D -1 /C "cmd /c del @path"
)
```

Comment: thx in advance, i will try as soon as possible (probaly tommorow or next week) :)